# Content-Type "application/json" not required in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an API endpoint in rails that by default if you do not set any Content-Type header processes the params in

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Is there a way to process a json string in rails from a POST request without specifying the content-type in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` file you can place the POST route within a namespace and define the format to expect like this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  post 'example' => 'controller#action'
end
```

In this case you would POST your json payload to '/api/example.json' and shouldn't have to define the Content-Type. You may also be able to define it for just the single post line, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: I believe :format 'json' defines the output format, not input format

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  resources :users
end
```